# Allow anonymous in conventional routing endpoint ASP .Net Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, oauth

I have a route that I want to allow anonymous configured like the following:

```
        app.UseMvc(routes =>
        {
            routes.MapRoute(
               name: "myEndpoint",
               template: "myendpoint",
               defaults: new { controller = "MyEndpoint", action = nameof(MyEndpoint.Get) }
            );
        });
```

The issue is that it redirects me to the oAuth page, I want `myendpoint` to allow anonymous users and bypass the oAuth page. I tried using the `AllowAnonymous` attribute in the method and class with no success.

This is my controller:

```
namespace MyNamespace
{
   /// <summary>
   /// My Endpoint API
   /// </summary>
   public class MyEndpointController : Controller
   {
       public MyEndpointController()
       {
       }

       /// <summary>
       /// My Endpoint
       /// </summary>
       public MyInfo Get()
       {
           return new Data
           {
              Data = Value
           };
       }
   }
}
```

Comment: Please add code of the controller where you apply `AllowAnonymous` attribute

Comment: Hi @Alexander I added the controller.

Comment: Thanks. I'll try it out

Comment: Hm, the controller itself doesn't contain `AuthorizeAttribute`. Did you configure global authentication? Maybe you can share that code as well?

Comment: I think it has global authentication, I'm new to this but it calls `AddAuthorization` in the services, and it has OAuth configured. The Startup class is very large but I will try to cut the unnecessary parts and post it.

Comment: `AllowAnonymous` works fine for me, hard to tell what's causing the issue in your case

Comment: Thanks @Alexander for testing the code. I solved it. The problem was that the call of `MapSpaFallbackRoute` was before the routing of `myendpoint`. More info on `MapSpaFallbackRoute` can be found [here](https://github.com/aspnet/JavaScriptServices/issues/973)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add [AllowAnonymous] to the home controller so anonymous users can get information about the site before they register.

```cs
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization;

namespace ContactManager.Controllers {
[AllowAnonymous]
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public IActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi @awais thanks for your response. I tried adding the attribute at method level and class level as you suggested but it didn't work. It only works when I use attribute routing but I want to use conventional routing.

Comment: Your answer @awais is correct, but there was a problem with my startup class. How I solved it is in my comments below the question.

Comment: hello @MauriR my startup class is like this and I have defined my default controller as well. It works fine with [AllowAnonymous] can you give a try.

public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
        {
           

            app.UseMvc(routes =>
            {
                routes.MapRoute(
                    name: "default",
                    template: "{controller=Account}/{action=Login}/{id?}");
            });
        }